# Mapping ORACLE Data Type to JAVA Data Type

Tags: java, oracle, orm, metadata, type-conversion

according to following code and table :

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

for( int i=1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++ ) {
    // label if defined else name of column
    String columnLabel = rsmd.getColumnLabel( i ); 

    // data type in database
    String columnType = rsmd.getColumnTypeName( i ); 

    // java equivalent class name
    String columnClassName = rsmd.getColumnClassName( i ); 

    System.out.println( "Column Name : " + columnLabel );
    System.out.println( "Column Type : " + columnType );
    System.out.println( "Column Class: " + columnClassName );

    System.out.println();
} // for count of columns
```

//--------------------- Table ----------------------------------

```
CREATE TABLE  "TEST123" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "AGE" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "AVERAGE" NUMBER(2,2)
   ) ;
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------

**Why output of numeric field, at table above, show java.math.BigDecimal ? we want the program shows integer, double, short and ... as result.**

```
-------------output------------------
Column Name : ID
Column Type : NUMBER
Column Class: java.math.BigDecimal

Column Name : NAME
Column Type : VARCHAR2
Column Class: java.lang.String

Column Name : AGE
Column Type : NUMBER
Column Class: java.math.BigDecimal

Column Name : AVERAGE
Column Type : NUMBER
Column Class: java.math.BigDecimal
```

Comment: Just use `BigDecimal.doubleValue()`

Comment: where do i use BigDecimal.doubleValue()?

Answer (score 0):

Read the record set with `recordSet.getBigDecimal(index).doubleValue()` or directly with `recordSet.getDouble(index)`